# Reduce whitespace above and below HTML text

Tags: html, css

I have the problem that my link text always adds unneeded space above and below the text. This happens only when my text has a line break. I guess it is because of the text font I'm using. I have some kind of fix for it, by using an inline-block, which removes somehow the space, but I want to preserve the line break in this text/link block. At the end I want to add a border line on the top and blow the link. When I'm adding the border, the border line appears at the end of the space, which looks not very nice. This is the reason I want to remove the unnecessary space.[image]
In the screenshot, the link has the css property: display: inline;

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
            <a class="link" href="target.html">
                This is a very very very long link...</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try to reduce line-height property?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `line-height`:

```
ul li {
   line-height: .8em;
}
```

Demo:

```css
ul { width: 200px; line-height: 1.5em; }
ul:last-of-type { line-height: .8em; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
            <a class="link" href="target.html">
                This is a very very very long link...</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat</p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
            <a class="link" href="target.html">
                This is a very very very long link...</a>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I also tried line-height, but unfortunately it has no effect on my element height. When I change the CSS property display to inline-block I'm able to change the element height, but it also shifts my element text into a new line, what I dont want.

Comment: As you can see in my demo, line-height should do the trick. Isn't there some code elsewhere overwriting it?

Comment: I tried it again and line-height is working, but in my example I'm already at the minimum line-height. Font-size, of course, also works, but I want to keep the same font-size in my text. The actual problem I really have, is the linebreak. When I have a line break (due to the display: inline), the font size stays the same. but the free space above the text increases. An this leads to problem with the board I've added to the text. I also will add a picture, to show the problem with the border.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the height your text occupies with `line-height` and `font-size`. But I think what you want is `line-height`. Try decreasing its value.

Comment: I tried it again and `line-height` is working, but in my example I'm already at the minimum `line-height`. Font-size, of course, also works, but I want to keep the same `font-size` in my text. The actual problem I really have, is the linebreak. When I have a line break (due to the `display: inline`), the font size stays the same. but the free space above the text increases. An this leads to problem with the board I've added to the text. I also will add a picture, to show the problem with the border.